# WooCoomerce WC_Abstract_Order::get_coupon_codes PHP Fatal Error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, coupon

I'm trying to use new WC_Abstract_Order::get_coupon_codes() methods to get coupon codes in an order. This was the previous working snippet:

```
$coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();

$nCoupons = count($coupons);
            if($nCoupons == 1)
                $descrizioneCoupon = 'Coupon ' . $coupons[0];
            else if($nCoupons > 1)
            {
                $descrizioneCoupon = 'Coupons ';
                for($i=0;$i<$nCoupons;$i++)
                {
                    $descrizioneCoupon .= $coupons[$i];
                    if($i<$nCoupons-1)
                    {
                        $descrizioneCoupon .= ', ';
                    }
                }
            }
```

So I'm trying to replace the first line with this one:

```
$coupons = \WC_Abstract_Order::get_coupon_codes();
```

I'm doing this since `get_used_coupons()` is deprecated.

As a result I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context ...
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I tested my code replacing the old method with the new ($order->get_coupon_codes) and it works, thanks. I didn't know what was the new method to get coupon codes. My fault was that I wasn't enough clear in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is simply to replace:

```
$coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();
// OR: 
// $coupons = \WC_Abstract_Order::get_coupon_codes();
```

by:

```
$order->get_coupon_codes();
```

> Don't use `\WC_Abstract_Order`, always use the `WC_Order` instance object `$order`